# Reset a patch with switch on NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I need some help to resolve one doubt. I have 5 types of patches in colors, blue, orange, red, green and yellow. I would like the orange and red patch to be inactive if a switch (named show? in the interface) was enabled. I am doing the following code (below). But it is not working. Everything remains the same. Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
to test
  if show? = false [
   ask patches with [pcolor = orange and pcolor = red ] [
     set pcolor black
     set plabel "" ]
]
  if show? = true [ color-map ] ;; color-map is procedure with the 5 patches colors
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a small logical error: a patch can't have
`pcolor = orange and pcolor = red`

Just replace the `and` by `or`

Comment: Hi Lena. Thanks for your answer, but did not work!

Comment: Maybe I don't get your problem. After changing the value of the switch, you must run `test` again, in order to see changes

Comment: Hi Lena, Thanks again. You are right! Solved the problem! :)